# Problem with PHP CS Fixer using PhpStorm 2018 under Windows 10

Tags: git, laravel, phpstorm, homestead, php-cs-fixer

So, given that I'm using:

- Windows 10;
- PhpStorm 2018
- Developing a Laravel project under homestead

When I try to commit in PhpStorm using git (have a couple of git hooks) it fires an error regarding php-cs-fixer:

> 'php-cs-fixer' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I have php-cs-fixer installed globally, both in Windows and Homestead.

I tried some solutions that I found, like trying to put php-cs-fixer as an external tool in PhpStorm and a couple more stuff, but it got me nowhere.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the global Composer binaries directory in your `PATH`

Comment: Yeap that was it, forgot to check it, tks ;)